# Joomla - additional search ordering option

Tags: search, joomla, joomla1.5

Looking at adding an additional search ordering option but not sure how to go about doing it as I have little to no Joomla experience.

Currently the default search ordering options are

- Newest First
- Oldest First
- Most Popular
- Alphabetical
- Section/Category

I think I have located the code that generates these options in \components\com_search\views\search\view.html.php

```
$orders = array();
$orders[] = JHTML::_('select.option',  'newest', JText::_( 'Newest first' ) );
$orders[] = JHTML::_('select.option',  'oldest', JText::_( 'Oldest first' ) );
$orders[] = JHTML::_('select.option',  'popular', JText::_( 'Most popular' ) );
$orders[] = JHTML::_('select.option',  'alpha', JText::_( 'Alphabetical' ) );
$orders[] = JHTML::_('select.option',  'category', JText::_( 'Section/Category' ) );
```

Do I add the additional option here or is this a core file that I shouldn't edit? If so, how can I go about adding an additional search ordering option?

Thank you

Comment: For now I have copied com_search/search/default_form.php and written the select element out on the page with the additional option. Any other ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can edit any core file. However you would have to be prepared to readd this edit in every time you update Joomla!

However any default.php file should be copied into and done as a template override. If you're planning on adding to the search functionality - a view.html.php file CAN'T be done as a template override. The best way to do it in this case would be to add a plugin to give this functionality.

For how to add a plugin giving this extra functionality see the documentation pages:
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_search_plugin
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Smart_Search_plug-in